# Why is 'DataFrame' object not callable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, typeerror

I have used Python for years and am trying to get more familiar with Pandas. I keep finding things that do not seem Pythonic to me. In this case, I want to use the largest value from my DataFrame to build a range object but I find that I cannot make an integer to feed to the range() function from the float returned as the maximum value of my DataFrame. As a minimal reproducible example, here is some code illustrating the error.

```
# Create a DataFrame 
pairs = pd.DataFrame({'Pair': ['A-B', 'A-C'], 'Distance': [54.3, 9009.122894715296]})

# Select the max
pairs['Distance'].max()
9009.122894715296

# Check the type
type(pairs['Distance'].max())
<class 'float'>

# Make an integer to use in range function
int(pairs['Distance'].max())

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

I have never had an issue converting a float to an integer so I do not understand why a) it is calling it a DataFrame object when it is clearly a float and b) it cannot convert this float to an integer. Hopefully someone has some knowledge of the operations that lead to this error.

Comment: You haven't previously redefined `int` in your interactive session, have you?

Comment: Can you add a `print(int)` right before the line that raises an error? I have a feeling you may have shadowed the builtin `int` type with a variable containing a DataFrame.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it - you're sure this particular piece of code is causing this error? - my hint - you might put somewhere thing like: `pairs()` - it would cause an error phrased exactly like what you're getting...

Comment: Oh no! I did redefine int. What do I do about the question now. Does someone want to post it as an answer and I can accept it. Thanks for helping me through that silly mistake.